# Azure DevOps release pipeline custom template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Using the classic (visual) designer, how do you create a custom template for the release pipeline?  For the build pipeline, when I click the ellipse in the upper right corner (three vertical dots) I see the command "Save as a template", but no such command exists for the release pipeline.

Comment: How is your problem progressing?

Comment: As noted in the thread below, I found the answer [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/244106/creating-a-release-template.html). Thanks for checking.

Comment: You can convert it into an answer, it can help other community members who get the same issues more easily to find the solution and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

so there are several options:

1. create a task group and use that across releases
2. create a "sample" release and clone it
3. export a release and import it (but this will need some editing afterwards, i believe)

I believe task groups are better overall solution, because they give you the ability to mass edit release (effectively). So they give more manageability\flexibility

Comment: I found the answer here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/244106/creating-a-release-template.html. Basically, I need select a stage first within a release pipeline. Click the ellipse in the upper corner (three horizontal dots), then "Save as template".

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/244106/creating-a-release-template.html). Basically, I need select a stage first within a release pipeline. Click the ellipse in the upper corner (three horizontal dots), then "Save as template".

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could Accept it as an Answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.